# How should I add Eagle Scout to my Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I am an [Eagle Scout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Scout_%28Boy_Scouts_of_America%29) and I want to display my rank on my Developer Story.

I'm aware that Eagle Scout isn't *technically* related to programming, but [as a student who just finished college](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/24460/68427), I feel that Eagle Scout is an accomplishment worth listing.

How should I feature my work as an Eagle Scout on my Developer Story?

Comment: I'd think Milestone would work.

Comment: Congratulations on both Eagle Scout and finishing college.

Comment: @bluefeet What would I put down for category?

Comment: The category for that would be "milestone".

Comment: @StevenVascellaro The item type is Milestone > Category could be youth organization or something similar, then Title could be eagle scout.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Under the "Education" tab, there is a text box for "Summary or achievements." The verbatim default text is:

> Which projects are you most proud of? Were you involved in any student groups? Did you receive any awards or recognition?

That sounds like the perfect place to put your Eagle Award. It is a significant accomplishment.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add this to your resume, other answers and comments suggest ways to do that.

However, I'd think twice before doing that. As proud as you may be of your Eagle Scout status, if you have now graduated from college then it is something that happened a relatively long time ago; it might well be no more relevant than having been president of your high school drama club.

Then there is the problem that there may be people looking at your resume for whom the association with Boy Scouts or Eagle status could be a negative, especially for companies on the east or west coasts. For instance, some people might associate you with the Scouts' [erstwhile homophobia](http://www.slate.com/blogs/xx_factor/2013/04/19/boy_scouts_gay_ban_lifted_but_still_homophobic.html). The Scouts continue to insist that you [must believe in God](https://blog.scoutingmagazine.org/2014/10/03/belief-in-god-scouting/). Others might associate you with Eagle Scout [Ryan Zinke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Zinke), Secretary of the Interior under current US President Donald J. Trump, who is now proposing to [un-designate national monuments](http://www.salon.com/2017/08/08/trump-and-ryan-zinke-may-want-to-shrink-national-monument-boundaries-but-history-points-the-other-way/) and [drill for oil in national parks](http://trib.com/business/energy/interior-secretary-orders-faster-permitting-of-oil-and-gas-drilling/article_7a2ab4ac-b20c-5f8e-879d-e1a619b045e7.html).

Then again, [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/EngineeringStudents/comments/5z2urf/should_i_include_eagle_scout_on_my_resume/) seems to support listing this award.

I am an Eagle Scout myself, but personally never found this particular award to be of much relevance in getting a job or anything else.

Comment: I really don't disagree with what you're saying here...but the question *is* asking "how" and not "should I".

Comment: For a recent college graduate I don't think that a major accomplishment like that in high school is to old to put on a resume. I also think you are over estimating the negative press that some people have gotten and most people won't look at boy scouts participation in a negative light.

Comment: @Makoto It is an interesting point. Would it be  appropriate to ask "Should I list Eagle" on MSO? Or would that be off-topic?

Comment: @stevenvascellaro it woyld probably be off topic. Your question as is.

Comment: @stevenvascellaro but for what it is worth, I too am an Eagle Scout. Put it on your resume while looking for a job. After you've worked your first job though, that experience is what will get you to your next one.

Comment: Downvoted this answer because it does not answer the "how" question and is off-topic. However, it would be a good answer for the already [linked question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/when-should-i-stop-listing-eagle-scout-on-my-resume) in Workplace.SE.

Comment: So true. Having been a distant observer of the recent covfefe over allowing gay boys to join the Scouts, my gut reaction to someone stating that they've been an Eagle Scout is not exactly approval. It isn't entirely a rational reaction, but I know that I am not alone in feeling that way, either. And I don't even live on the east or west coasts. :-)

Comment: @Makoto From time to time, there's a XY problem. The question is "How do I do X" and the answer is "Don't do X"